# ButtonCellEditor doesn't select row of Jtable

Tags: swing, jtable, selection, jbutton

I have a custom cell renderer and editor for a JButton. My Problem is if I click on a button, the according row doesn't get selected.

It's needed because the ActionListener of the button needs to get the information of the clicked row.

How can I implement this behaviour?

Edit:

I have a class which contains a `JTable` in combination with a `DefaultListModel`. This table visualizes an Object each row. Additionally each row contains a Modify- and Delete-Button implemented with the `ButtonColumn`below. The row itself doesn't contain the real data - it only contains plain Strings. If I click now on the Modify- or Delete-Button I want to do something on the real object (which is stored in an interal `ArrayList`) - Therefore I need the information in which row the button is clicked.

```
class ButtonColumn extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellRenderer,
                                                         TableCellEditor
{
    private JButton btRenderer = new JButton();
    private JButton btEdit     = new JButton();
    private String text;

    public ButtonColumn(ActionListener listener, String actionCommand)
    {
        btEdit.setFocusPainted(false);
        btEdit.addActionListener(listener);
        btEdit.setActionCommand(actionCommand);
    }

    public void addMouseListener(MouseListener listener)
    {
        btEdit.addMouseListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                                Object value,
                                                boolean isSelected,
                                                boolean hasFocus,
                                                int row,
                                                int column)
    {
        btRenderer.setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
        return btRenderer;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,
                                                Object value,
                                                boolean isSelected,
                                                int row,
                                                int column)
    {
        text = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
        btEdit.setText(text);
        return btEdit;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue()
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: a) sounds like something wrong in the code you are not showing b) sounds fishy that you need the selected row additionally to the row as passed into the editor in getTableCellEditorComponent( ... _row_ .. )

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by adding another custom `MouseListener` to my ButtomCellRenderer/Editor which is implemented in the table class.

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    clickedRowIndex = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
}
```

There I can get the information which cell is clicked if I click on a `ButtonCell` and can use this information in the `actionPerformed`method.

Comment: This seems rather circuitous. This [tutorial example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor) shows the standard appraoch. Can you elaborate?

Comment: this "fix" most probably is simply hiding a deeper problem with your code. Better dig for the real issue now than suffer later :-)

Comment: I've edited the problem - My problem is that I don't store the actual objects inside the JTable, only plain data.

Comment: you _have_ the row, see my comment to your question, especially bullet b

Comment: yes, inside the ButtonColumn I have the row. But not outside. I need the row the actionPerformed() of the button.

Comment: now you lost me - we are talking cellEditor here, or not? BTW: your editor implemenation is invalid (it must notify its listeners when editing is terminated for internal reasons, f.i. when clicking on one)

Comment: Thanks for that tip. My general behaviour is that i want to edit/delete an object if I click on one button. In my class which contains the JTable, I implement an ActionListener for the ButtonColumns which is set in the constructor. This ActionListener now needs the Information which button is pressed.

Comment: still don't get it: that button is part of the cellEditor, right? If so, implement a custom action/Listener which has a row property and set that row property in getCellEditorComponent ...